# Replace an attribute value with another value in SVG

Tags: bash, sed, replace, svg

I have a directory that contains multiple SVG files. What I am trying to do is replace the `height="2500"` (value of height can be any integer) with `height="{{ include.height }}"`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2232" height="2500" viewBox="32.163 68.509 203.691 228.155"><path d="M101.885 207.092c7.865 0 14.241 6.376 14.241 14.241v61.09c0 7.865-6.376 14.24-14.241 14.24-7.864 0-14.24-6.375-14.24-14.24v-61.09c0-7.864 6.376-14.24 14.24-14.24z" fill="#a4c639"/></svg>
```

```bsh
find_string="height=\"\d+\""
replace_string="height=\"{{ include.height }}\""
for i in . -type f -name "*.svg");
do
    if grep -q "${find_string}" $i
    then
        sed -i -r "s/${find_string}/${replace_string}/" $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: What is happening instead of what you expect? Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Also, for `grep` to understand `\d`, you need to use `grep -P`.

Comment: Are your files all in the same directory, or do you need to recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: Don't use 'sed' to parse XML/SVG

Comment: `sed` doesn't understand `\d`, use `[0-9]`.

Comment: Please fix that for loop. It is positively klunky.

Comment: @RakeshSharma if the OP knew how to fix it, they probably wouldn't be asking here.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you're doing wrong is that you are confusing the syntax of the command `find` with the syntax of the shell builtin `for`:

```
for i in . -type f -name "*.svg");
```

That doesn't mean anything. You can do this:

```
for i in *.svg
```

Or this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.svg"
```

But you can't combine them the way you did. You also have a trailing parenthesis there, but let's ignore that.

Next, you are using a needless `grep`. You are processing all files with `grep` and then processing some of them again with `sed`. That doesn't make anything more efficient, if you're going to read the file anyway, you may as well make the replacement wherever needed.

Finally, you can use single quotes so you don't need to escape the double quote, and `sed` doesn't understand `\d`, so use `[0-9]` instead.

So, this should do what you want *if the files are all in the same directory*:

```
find_string='height="[0-9]+"'
replace_string='height="{{ include.height }}"'
for i in *.svg;
do
     sed -i -E "s/${find_string}/${replace_string}/" "$i"
done
```

If you need to recurse into subdirectories, you can use `find` instead. If you are 100% sure your file names have no spaces, newlines or other whitespace, you can simply do:

```
find_string='height="[0-9]+"'
replace_string='height="{{ include.height }}"'
find . -type f -name '*.svg' | while read i; do
    sed -i -E "s/${find_string}/${replace_string}/" "$i"
done
```

Or, to deal with arbitrary file names, assuming you have GNU `find`, use:

```
find_string='height="[0-9]+"'
replace_string='height="{{ include.height }}"'
find . -type f -name '*.svg' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
    sed -i -E "s/${find_string}/${replace_string}/" "$i"
done
```

Alternatively, if you're using `bash`, you can do:

```
shopt -s globstar
find_string='height="[0-9]+"'
replace_string='height="{{ include.height }}"'
for i in **/*.svg;
do
    sed -i -E "s/${find_string}/${replace_string}/" "$i"
done
```

Comment: The find_string regex should be: `height="[0-9]+"`[

Comment: @RakeshSharma fair enough, I was assuming GNU sed. I added a note, thanks.

Comment: '@terdon Even with `-E` turned on, gnu sed doesn't take `\d` for a digit. Atleast till gnu sed 4.5 is what I can see.

Comment: @RakeshSharma you're absolutely right. I could have sworn I had tested this, but apparently not. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the interruption, but find alone is enuf no need to pipe filenames. In fact it's the most secure (can handle all sorts of filenames) can invoke sed with >1 files(so speed gain), and it's all Posixly.

Comment: @RakeshSharma sure, but I didn't want to go into `-exec` here, I wanted to stick as close as possible to what the OP was doing. That said, the glob approach is just as secure as `find` and, in most cases, just as fast (unless you have to recurse very deeply and have hundreds of thousands of files). But do feel free to post an answer with `find -exec`, that would be useful!